# Issue with MyBatis @Select with foreach loop

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I am trying to fetch data from a table using @Select annotation of mybatis and postgresql database in backend.

Below is the query and method for mybatis mapper

```
@Select(
  "<script>"
      + "SELECT distinct we_pid FROM we_data_model.snapshot_link WHERE cast (id as uuid) IN "
      + "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='subListSnapshot'"
      + " open='(' separator=',' close=')'>"
      + " #{item}"
      + "</foreach>"
      + "</script>")
List<Integer> selectWePidsFromSnapshot(@Param("subListSnapshot") List<String> 
subListSnapshot);
```

I am trying to pass UUIDs like 14ef69d0-fcfe-11ec-b006-d52b0da9de8d in string format to this method and when i pass one or two UUIDs it works fine but when i pass 4 or 5 it shows with an error shown below

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
Error querying database.  Cause: 
org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 
'we_pid' from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for 
type int : 2,312,106,391
```

I have verified the data that is sent to the method which are correct ids like 1507d3d1-fcfe-11ec-b006-d52b0da9de8d, 14ffbd82-fcfe-11ec-b006-d52b0da9de8d, 14ee7f70-fcfe-11ec-b006-d52b0da9de8d, 14ef69d0-fcfe-11ec-b006-d52b0da9de8d but not sure why its converting the data to those integers.

Comment: @Dev The error says that the returned value of `we_pid` exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The return type of the method ought to be `List<Long>`, maybe?

Comment: ok let me try that and check

Comment: @TheImpaler '#{item}' doesnt work along with quotes. It throws an error

Comment: Can you run the query manually and find the min and max values returned for `we_pid`? I think @ave may be right.

Comment: The suggestion made by @ave worked